# How to change scrollbar colors using ScrollBarRenderer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm developing a Winforms application and need to set design of scrollbar. I need to change colors of arrows, slider and background of a track. I found a ScrollBarRenderer on msdn [msdn ScrollBarRenderer Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbarrenderer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and now I don't understand how to set up rendering via methods like

```
ScrollBarRenderer.DrawRightHorizontalTrack(e.Graphics,
            ClientRectangle, ScrollBarState.Normal);

        // Draw the thumb and thumb grip in the current state.
        ScrollBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalThumb(e.Graphics,
            thumbRectangle, thumbState);
        ScrollBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalThumbGrip(e.Graphics,
            thumbRectangle, thumbState);
```

This code is executed in OnPaint.

I'll be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly the ScrollBar is just a wrapper around the native Win32 API, which doesn't expose the the colors of the bar.

Other controls allow you to extend a custom renderer and use that, but because the scroll bar simply links through to Win32 calls, you can't do that here.

The only way to achieve this is to create a custom draw scroll bar class extending from Control, as this example on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41869/Custom-Drawn-Scrollbar) shows.

---

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41869/Custom-Drawn-Scrollbar